# non expired cookie appearing as expired in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cookies

After a lot of tests I can't figure out where the problem comes from.

I have a controller with this:

```
Cookie::queue('email', 'test@test.te', 60 * 24 * 365);
```

I use queue because the response is a json coming from an ajax.

Then in my view:

```
{{ cookie('email') }}
```

And the response is:

> email=deleted; expires=Mon, 18-Dec-2017 09:55:51 GMT; Max-Age=0;
>   path=/; httponly

I see that the cookie is created expiring in 1 year, but I still reload the page just in case, but same result.
I've tried different cookie names just in case, like 'sdfsdfad43fsa' but same result.

I obtain the same result if I try laravel_sesion.

If I try:

```
{{ Cookie::get('laravel_sesion') }}
```

It works, but not in the case of "email"

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Pretty simple right? I don't get what I'm doing wrong? Maybe some CSRF or some other issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
var_dump(Cookie::get('email'))
```

You will see that you are probably sending an array, maybe you forgot to clean the cookies from a previous saving.

Additionally use this one to retrieve the cookie:

```
{{ Cookie::get('email') }}
```

Peace